# What is the difference between var {todo}= require("./models/todo"); and var todo=require("./models/todo");

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to load a todo model from my todo class and I have two options. The first one is

```
var {todo}= require("./models/todo");
```

and second one is

```
var todo=require("./models/todo");
```

I am confused which is what.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a destructuring assignment. It means "take an object from "models/todo" and assign its property "todo" to my local variable "todo". If it contains no such property, you'll get undefined assigned to the variable.

Answer (score -1):

For example this if is your model

```
module.exports = {
    toLower: obj => {



    },
    streamIdea: async (idea) => {


    }
}
```

if you're doing this

```
 const model = require('mymodel');
```

then you have to call your functions like this,

```
 model.toLower()
```

which means you're importing everything and calling it by function name

and if you're importing like this:

```
const { toLower } = require('mymodel');
```

it means you're only importing `toLower` from this model now you can just call it like this

```
 toLower();
```

without need of `model.`